Error when trying to append a string to a hashmap list
i get this Error, when i try to append something to my hashmap:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
i think its because my hashmap key is a str, but im not sure.
my code:
strs = ["act","pots","tops","cat","stop","hat"]

seen = {}

for s in strs:
    sorted = list(strs[s])
    sorted.sort()
    seen[sorted].append(s)


print (sorted)


is there an easy way to fix this or do i have to change my approach?

When you iterate over your list, for s in strs, you assign the values of the list to s.
e.g. The first loop iteration will assign "act" to s.
Additionally, you're sorting each iteration which is most likely not what you intended.
Usually, such operations have handy functions/methods that do the sorting for you and you don't need to implement any such algorithm but call them once.
Lastly, you're close to what you're trying to do. The syntax to assign a value to a hash "bucket" is dict_var[key_name] = value.
Good luck.

hey, thanks for the help :)
i tried "dict_var[key_name] = value.", but i get the error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

@Chili there are a few prerequisites you need to tackle before you can complete your task. 1) What are the different data types you are using (in this case list, "hashmap" aka dict in Python). 2) What is a loop? Can you implement one that prints each item in the strs list without using for? 3) What is iterating over a list (or compatible data type). There aren't available characters in a comment to cover all these fundamental topics. But they are detrimental in solving the above. Good luck!
